# How to statistically compare frequency / distribution over time?

Tags: time-series, distributions

Imagine this (illustrative) situation: there's a lake and in this lake 4 different fish species live. Every day for a year I count how many fishes there are in the lake (complete census, not sampling), and at the end of the year I make a nice plot, where it shows every month the percentage of each species in the lake, like so:

[image]

Let's suppose that my H0 is that time has no influence in the distribution of fishes, and my H1 is instead being able to say "time does have an effect in fish population".

What's the most appropriate statistical approach to test this hypothesis? Also, is there a way to tell which month / period in specific has the most influence?

If this was not a time series but simply categorical data, I would probably start with a Chi-square test for independence followed by a Cronbach's Alpha to see which groups are most divergent from the mean, but in the case of a timeseries I'm totally lost.

I'm quite noob at stats so any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In row $i$ of a table put frequencies (not %s) of Species $i$ fish observed each month. Then you will have a $4\times 12$ matrix of observed counts.

I suppose you have a standard method of sampling and counting
fish each month and that you are not catching anywhere near
the total number of fish each time. (If you are able to do a
complete census of fish each day, then you have numbers in the population and there nothing to test.)

Then do a chi-squared test of homogeneity on your matrix.

*Example:* You might have counts in matrix `MAT` as
follows (fictitious counts sampled using R):

```
 MAT
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
x1  955  975  989 1005 1030  986  960  938  968  1013   977   998
x2 1427 1400 1395 1408 1460 1405 1397 1416 1394  1391  1401  1395
x3  875  917  914  896  875  842  860  942  902   845   903   857
x4 1904 1996 2048 2013 2045 2109 1989 2022 1972  2022  1981  2037
x5 2251 2107 2158 2174 2155 2187 2192 2180 2269  2169  2145  2236
```

A chi-squared test shows homogeneity of observed counts across the 12 'months': the large P-value $0.5391 > 0.05 = 5/%$ shows that the data
are consistent with a homogeneous distribution.

```
chisq.test(MAT)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 42.43, df = 44, p-value = 0.5391
```

*Note:* Fictitious counts were sampled in R with 12 counts
from a Poisson distribution of the same mean in each row.

```
set.seed(617)
x1 = rpois(12, 1000);  x2=  rpois(12, 1400)
x3 = rpois(12, 900);   x4 = rpois(12,2000)
x5 = rpois(12, 2200)
MAT = rbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation. I didn't know I could use a chi-square even for timeseries.

`If you are able to do a complete census`
With respect to this: I am able to do a complete census (the fish thing was just an example to describe the situation I'm dealing with, I could have used something else, like product types in a warehouse).

Comment: Concerns remain whether the sampling procedures across time are independent. Not sure how realistic your 'fish' analogy is. Fish might breed or die from one measurement to the next. (Differential birth/death rates among species would be the point of the study.) If you are doing a 10% sample of fish each time, I would not worry about independence. But it it's more like 90%, I would look for other ways to model this.

Comment: So maybe the fish analogy wasn't adequate. The actual situation, simplified, is product sales from an e-commerce, like I dunno, beverages, and imagine that said beverages are fanta, coke, 7up and sprite. The question is "does time influence the distribution of sales of these beverages, with respect to each other?". I don't care about the absolute quantity of a single product sales, but how it performs with respect to other products. So if my average 7up sales is 30% of the total, and in June is 35%, is it due to chance / variance or is it significant enough to reject H0 ?

Comment: But the issue of randomness remains. Do you have nationwide beverage sales each month? Or do you have monthly surveys from 1000 customers? // If chi-sq statistic with DF=44 were **below** about 30 I'd question the model. // If I ask a student to roll a die 600 times and report counts and they gave 101, 100, 99, 100, 100, 100, then I'd wonder whether dice were really rolled.

Comment: I think I get what you mean, you're questioning if the data is properly sampled without bias? From that perspective, the data belongs to a specific e-commerce and I have all sales numbers, so for any product I know how much it sold. If you put it that way, of course I don't have any info about other people buying the same products elsewhere.